# Ionic Angular Passing data between views

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to create 3 Pages where ;

In page A there's a formgroup, after it fills and click submit btn, then it will go to the Page B.

In Page B there's only a confirmation statement. so user only have to choose Agree or Disagree.

If user choose Agree on Page B then goes to Page C and shown all information/data from Page A.

My question is, is it possible to pass the data(name,email,id) from page A directly to C while the  flow of the views must be A > B > C.

Can i achieve this with ionic angular?

[image: This is the example of the pages flow]

Answer (score 2):

You can save the data in a subject inside a service in page A, and subscribe to the subject in page C to receive the data.
Same thing can be achieved with `ngrx` or any other state management library.

Simple example:

data.service.ts

```
// the service that has the subject that keeps the data
private data$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

setData(data: any){
  this.data$.next(data);
}

getData(){
  return this.data$.asObservable();
}
```

page-a.component.ts

```
submitForm(){
  //...
  this.dataService.setData(this.form.value);
}
```

page-c.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
  //...
  this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
    // do whatever you want with the data
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works as i expected

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Static Class to pass your data.

```
ionic g service globaldata
```

which you can share data.

inside your page A:

```
import {GlobalDataServe} from 'GlobaldataServer.ts'

gotoPageB(){
  GlobalDataServe.yourDataVariable = yourDataOnPageA;
  this.route.navigate('yourPageB');
}
```

Nothing to do on page B;

on page C import same class and get data

```
import {GlobalDataServe} from 'GlobaldataServer.ts

ionViewWilLEnter(){
 this.yourData = GlobalDataServe.yourDataVariable;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works as i expected